# How to have 2 lines in a block?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm using the `schemabloc package`, and I want to have 2 lines of text in a bloc...

`Diode` under `Protection`, and  `Oscillator` under `Boost` in the following example

Here it is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{schemabloc}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\sbEntree{E}
\sbBloc[3]{PV}{PV Cells}{E}
\sbDecaleNoeudy[-1.9]{PV}{PV2}
\sbBlocL[2]{B}{Battery}{PV}
\sbBlocL{D}{Protection \\ Diode}{B}      % Here
\sbRenvoi[-2]{PV2}{D}{}
\sbBlocL[2]{OS}{Boost/Oscillator}{D}     % And Here
\sbBlocL[2]{L}{LED}{OS} 
\sbSortie{S}{OS}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

And it's what I get :

```
./Sans-titre.tex:10: LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.10 \sbBlocL{D}{Protection \\ Diode}{B}
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Append the `align` key to the style `sbStyleBloc`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{schemabloc}
\tikzset{%
  sbStyleBloc/.append style = {align = center}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \sbEntree{E}
  \sbBloc[3]{PV}{PV Cells}{E}
  \sbDecaleNoeudy[-1.9]{PV}{PV2}
  \sbBlocL[2]{B}{Battery}{PV}
  \sbBlocL{D}{Protection \\ Diode}{B}
  \sbRenvoi[-2]{PV2}{D}{}
  \sbBlocL[2]{OS}{Boost \\ Oscillator}{D}
  \sbBlocL[2]{L}{LED}{OS} 
  \sbSortie{S}{OS}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```